# TypeScript and JS module import misunderstanding

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, node-modules, ecmascript-5

I thought that I understand how import works but today found I didn't.

Have pure javascript module like:

```
function MyClass() { ... }

util.inherits(MyClass, EventEmitter);

MyClass.prototype.someMethod = funtion(x) { ... }

...

module.exports = MyClass;
```

And now I am importing this module in TypeScript file (as I thought it uses the same syntaxt as ES6 import) and found that this works:

```
import * as MyWebSocket from '../utils/websocket';
```

And this - doesn't:

```
import MyWebSocket from '../utils/websocket';
```

Also this doesn't work either:

```
import { MyWebSocket } from '../utils/websocket';
```

As I understand `import X from Y` should works if module exports something with `default` keyword like `export default X` (and equal ES5 syntax is `module.exports = X`). And `import { X } from Y` should works if exporting something not-default (ans similat ES5 syntax is `module.exports = { X }`).

But I see I'm wrong. Could you please fix me?

Comment: did you try "esModuleInterop": true in tsconfig?

Comment: @Praveen tried but it makes other legacy part of code broken. For instance `Bluebird` was set as `global.Promise = Bluebird` and this becomes broken. Also many other parts of app doesn't compiles after that flag set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`module.exports = something` is NOT ES5 SYNTAX, actually there is no "module" in ES5 Spec. This module system is call CommonJS which adopted by Node.JS.

To make `import X from Y` from `module.exports = X` work in TypeScript, you should enabled `esModuleInterop: true`, otherwise, you MUST use `import * as X from Y`.